# Spacing within section titles

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

I'd be very glad if you could help me out with the following problem: I'm trying to reduce the spacing in my "\section{}"-text that spans two lines from 1,5 to 1,25. I couldn't find an appropriate solution online or by myself. (Unfortunately \begin{spacing}{1,25} \section{Here is the text that spans two lines.} \end{spacing} doesn't work because it also reduces the distance before and after the \section{}.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1,5}
\begin{document}

\section{Here is the text that spans two lines and that is supposed to have 1,25 spacing.}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can simply use this: `{\linespread{1.25}\section{my very longtitle}}`.

Comment: I've always thought that things like `\linespread` and `\setstretch` were bad hacks that were better handled through directly manipulating the `\baselineskip`, especially for things like double-spaced documents. But I guess all my efforts in the 90s to show an alternative route were for naught.

Comment: It seems to be a very local problem, so I guess it has no real importance – that's the simplest hack I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sectsty`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\linespread{1.25}\selectfont}
\setstretch{2.5}


\begin{document}

\section{Here is the text that spans two lines and that is supposed to have 1,25 spacing.}

Here is text that's spaced 2.5, which is \emph{really} too much.
Here is text that's spaced 2.5, which is \emph{really} too much.
Here is text that's spaced 2.5, which is \emph{really} too much.
Here is text that's spaced 2.5, which is \emph{really} too much,
but 1.5 is too much either.

\end{document}
```

I used 2.5 in order to emphasize the difference and show that the normal text uses the specified stretch.

[image]